# using Lodash for find property in complex object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, lodash

I have this db in mongoose:

```
xSchemaDef = {
questions: [],
editions:[{
    created: Date,
    responses: [{
        created: Date,
        answers: []
    }]
}]
```

how can I get all the answers properties of one edition using Lodash?
I tried :

```
y=_.pluck(xSchemaDef.editions, 'responses');
```

and got array of all responses array, but then I tried:

```
_.pluck(y, 'answers');
```

and got undefined. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first `pluck` will extraxt array of arrays. You can flatten it before you extract `answers`:

```
y = _.pluck(xSchemaDef.editions, 'responses');
_.pluck(_.flatten(y), 'answers');
```